# Is "heavens" used as a plural or singular?

Tags: grammar

According to Merriam Webster, while "Heaven" in singular form refers to the abode of God or gods, "heavens" in plural form refers to the sky or celestial space. Is it used as a plural or singular?

> The heavens is or are the sky or celestial realm.

The meaning makes me want to choose "is".

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OwqqfbinUDY

Comment: I can't open youtube, till someone helps me climb over GFW

Comment: Sorry - it was just a link to the well-known chorus "The Heavens are Telling the Glory of God" from Haydn's "The Creation". (Your profile gives no clue as to where you are. I had to look up 'GFW'.)

Comment: no worries. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Heavens appears 421 times in the old testament of the bible. In the original hebrew, it appears as a dual- a grammatical construct that is used in some languages for things that come in pairs (eyes, socks, etc). The dual is used because there is both the physical heaven- the sky above us, and the spiritual heaven- the abode of God.

Historically, When the plural was used in English other than the bible, it still carried this idea of the physical/spiritual heaven duality. Examples that still exist are expressions like "Good heavens!".

In modern English, it has lost this duality, and is mostly used in a literary sense to refer only to the physical sky, but it is still treated grammatically as a plural. Normal rules of grammar don't apply very strictly to literary English.

> The heavens [is/are] the sky or celestial realm.

The above sentence is incomplete because you are defining it only in terms of the physical heaven, so you are falling into a grammatical trap. To avoid that trap, you have to provide a complete definition:

> The heavens are the sky above us and the abode of God.

---

Interestingly, in the latin Vulgate bible, heaven (caelum) only appears in the singular:

> in principio creavit Deus caelum et terram

Presumably, when the King James translation into English was written, the translators referred back to the original hebrew text, and so they opted to use the plural heavens.